# Ignore empty datasets

Tags: u-sql

I writing a U-SQL Script that sometimes ends up with a empty data set. 
Today the outputter writes an empty file when that happens. I would like the outputter to not write anything when that happens. Since I will flood the ADLS with empty files... 
I have tried two things so far:

1. IF statement  - the problem here is that I do a select count(*) from the data set and I cannot do IF @COUNT > 0 since the @count is a data set and the if statement would like to have a variable.
2. Write a custom outputter – But I have notice that it is not the ouputter that writes the file but some other code that runs afterwards. The file gets created after the custom outputter is done.

Does anyone have any guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One method you can do is do cook your data into a table first. Then you can INSERT into the table instead of writing to a file.  Empty INSERTs do not cause job failure, nor will they affect performance at runtime or future performance on the table. Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that the files needs to be in ADLS since ADF cannot move data from ADLA tables.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update. Currently, this feature isn't supported.  However, dynamic partitioned output, a new feature currently in private preview, doesn't generate empty files when used. If you're interested in this, please send an email to usql at Microsoft dot com with a description of your scenario and we'll see if this will work for you.  You can also create a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake) to help improve ADL.